# Python ImportError , Can't Resolve

Tags: python, python-import

I'm working on an open source Python project and added a new module, `measure.py` to it and was trying to import and use it in another module I had added `measure_long.py`. However, I am running into a `ImportError` error.

Here is the structure of my project, named `opencensus-python`:

```
├── opencensus-python
│   ├── opencensus
│   │   ├── trace
│   │   │    │__  __init__.py
│   │   │    │__  measure.py 
│   │   │    │__  measure_long.py
│   │
```

Here is the code in `measure.py`. This runs fine, and I have an import statement in there that I don't use just to prove to myself that importing from that folder did work (so perhaps my `__init__.py` file is fine?)
[image]

Here is the code in 'measure.long.py`.

[image]

When I run it, here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "measure_long.py", line 2, in <module>
        from opencensus.trace import measure
ImportError: cannot import name 'measure' from 'opencensus.trace' (/Users/anamnavied/Documents/CSC492/opencensus-python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencensus/trace/__init__.py)
```

I've trouble shooted with a couple of stack overflow posts on import errors and did the following:

1. changed the absolute import statements to relative one: `from .measure import Measure` but get this error instead `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I debugged this according to another stack overflow post by adding a shebang to both Python files and running them as an executable script but still get the same ImportError.
2. I modified the `__init__.py` file, since that was what referenced in the error message. This was written by the original developers and contained the code marked **#original** and I added mine with comments: 
   [image]

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: `measure` is not a name which is importable from `opencensus.trace` (so from the `__init__.py`). Put a `import measure` in there and it should work.

Comment: @L3viathan I added this line to __init__.py `from opencensus.trace import measure` and added `'measure'` to the `__all__` list and it still produces the same `ImportError`.

Comment: That won't work, because now you're trying to import from `__init__.py` inside of itself. Literally do `import measure` inside the `__init__.py`

Comment: @L3viathan this worked, thank you!! Why was it neccessary to import it in `__init__.py`? Other classes weren't imported specifically in there and they worked so I'm curious if you may know

Comment: It depends on how you do the import. When you try to import something from `opencensus.trace` that means either the file `opencensus/trace.py` or `opencensus/trace/__init__.py`. You could still import things without that line by doing e.g. `from opencensus.trace.measure import Measure`